# Replicating a database that uses Fail Over

Tags: sql-server, failover

We are trying to setup replication for data coming in from an outside vendor. The issue that we are having is they say that because our vendor is using SQL Fail Over Clustering so they claim that the DB cant be replicated? Is that true and is there any work arounds.

Comment: Thank you all for your quick response. Yes the "they" was the vendor. We are working with them to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of your setup, but I've set up SQL Replication in every combination of standalone, Windows clustering, default and named instance.  I have not set up replication on an availability group db.

Need more explanation on who is saying what to contribute more.  Are "they" the vendor, or are there 3 parties to this?

Comment: Replication works fine with AGs too, though you do need to run an additional stored procedure to redirect it to the listener.

Answer (score 1):

That is not true. I've done transactional replication with FCIs for years. Interestingly I cannot find any supporting documentation on the Microsoft site, however it is supported, and it does work.

Answer (score 1):

They are incorrect if they are talking about Failover Clustering and SQL Server Replication. I have used Transactional Replication on numerous Failover Cluster Instances, on various versions.